# Закрывается excel при запуске макроса

Tags: excel, vba

После запуска макроса открывается первый документ на обновление связей. В процессе работы закрываются и макрос, и документ, который нужно обновить. При этом в Debug'е при последовательном выполнении всё открывает нормально и не ругается. В чем может быть проблема?

```
Dim DDS As String
DDS = Dir("Z:\Тех.файлы\Реестр ДДС *********.xlsx")
Do While DDS <> ""
Workbooks.Open "Z:\Тех.файлы\" & DDS
 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
DDS = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: На обновление связей нужно время, VBA процессом обновления не управляет

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA не совсем понял, что это значит.

Comment: @Acinit, в процессе работы скрипта

Comment: Вот поневоле возникает ещё один вопрос вопрос - а с чего Вы решили, что RefreshAll не изменяет ActiveWorkbook? Надо получать ссылку на книгу от Workbooks.Open, и все операции проводить именно на этом объекте. PS. И звезды в шаблоне достаточно одной...

Comment: @Akina, я не знаю изменяет ли Refresh ActiveWorkBook, но факт такой, что весь прошедший месяц до сегодняшнего дня макрос работал без ошибок.

Comment: Нашел возможную причину проблемы.  Макрос работает нормально, если некоторые файлы "Реестр ДДС *" убрать из папки. По каким причинам может возникать конфликт?